# Django Admin - customize use jquery inside and custom fields

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin, django-imagekit

I want to implement in Django Admin a jquery plugin that "adjust" and image(http://guillotine.js.org/), them get the coordinates with ImageKit and save the new image.

I need some tutorials and advises how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no tutorials, but can give you advice.
You can customize your admin model with custom css and js, by `Media` class, like so:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

You can look in dev tools, how Django chose names id's and classes for elements in page and also check the docs.
[Admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions)